# How to access to the DBContext used in an EntityManager?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, devforce

I insert/update a large amount of entities (~5000) during a process and this is taking a huge amount of time (it timeout on a 5 minutes transaction).

I read that by default the DBContext.AutoDetectChangesEnabled is set to ON and cause this kind of behavior (http://www.exsertus.be/2014/10/ef-bulk-performance/).

To my understanding, Devforce "kind of" encapsulate a DBContext within each EntityManager. Devforce use it's own implementation unless I define mine which I did. I would like to know how can I access it to be able to "play" with this property AutoDetectChangesEnabled.

Or are there any other solution to insert/update/delete large amount of entities with Devforce ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've defined your own DbContext you can alter this property setting in the DbContext constructor with `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

However, I'm not sure how much this change will help.  If your application is n-tier and you're trying to save ~5000 entities across the wire this will always be slow, and you'll also run into communication timeouts.  Generally if you need to do any bulk operations DevForce isn't the optimal approach.

Comment: Hi kim. What would be the best approach considering all the application/model is based on devforce ? Also I noticed when I call SavesChanges() I can wait more than 1 minute to see the first SQL order being sent to SQL server, why is it so long to generate the SQL. I have no clue who generates it, Devforce or EF ...

Comment: EF generates the SQL, but there could be a lot more going on than just SQL generation making it slow.  Although I don't have any experience with them, if the bulk operations are not part of your main application I would look at using the EF utilities.  If you want someone from IdeaBlade to take a look at this further, please open a tech support case via the web support form.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with this EF tool "https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFUtilities" and I got big performance enhancement with large inserts,  as it uses bulk copy instead of normal insert per entity.

You can check the documentation of Github [here](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities).

I have used it with a 17,000 entities insert transaction and it finished it in a few seconds. 
Check this to get a better understanding and comparison with EF. 
http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/entity-framework-batch-operations-using-ef-utilities/

A sample of using the utility to insert a list of entities is like this:

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    EFBatchOperation.For(db, db.BlogPosts).InsertAll(list);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunatly I can't use this as I need primary key fixup

Comment: You mean you generate your ids? If this is the case then that's fine because the tool works on your entities but instead of attaching them to the context and save them one by one,  this tool will push them all in one go.  The library definitely worth a try.

Comment: @kdev I guess you mean you are actually inserting to two tables and need to point the child rows to their parents? This is a hard problem if you are using database generated id's for the parent. (I always switch to guid or similar in these situations).

Comment: @kdev If you update your question with the relevant part of the entities you are inserting I might be able to help. 

I'm the author of EFUtilities so I've been thinking about these cases quite a bit.